# Clash between bibentry and hyperref with bibstyle elsart-harv

Tags: bibtex, hyperref, citing, bibentry

I'm using the `bibentry` package for inserting my bibitems into a CV without printing the bibliography. This works just fine until I load `hyperref`. Then I get the error message `Lonely \item--perhaps a missing list environment`. There is supposed to be a workaround ([see here](http://www.tug.org/applications/hyperref/ftp/README)), which I included as deactivated in the code below. When using it, I still get the error message. Is there another solution (no biblatex please) or am I not using the workaround correctly?

```
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@Book{elvis,
    author = "Elvis Presley",
    title = "Turn Me One More Time",
    publisher = "Jail House Books",
    year = 1963,
}
\end{filecontents}
\documentclass{article}
%\makeatletter
%\let\saved@bibitem\@bibitem
%\makeatother
\usepackage{bibentry}
\nobibliography*
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\bibentry{elvis}
%\bibliographystyle{plain}           % works fine
\bibliographystyle{elsart-harv}     % gives an error
\nobibliography{\jobname}       % comment out when using the workaround
%\begingroup
%\makeatletter
%\let\@bibitem\saved@bibitem
%\nobibliography{\jobname}
%\endgroup
\end{document}
```

---

EDIT:  Turns out, the problem is not just about `bibentry` and `hyperref`. For your convenience I replaced my actual bib-style [elsart-harv](http://www.elsevier.com/framework_authors/misc/elsart-harv.bst) with `plain`. It didn't come to my mind that the style could be the crux of this matter, but it obviously is.

Comment: Your example (plus workaround) works for me. Try to update your TeX distribution and/or delete all auxiliary files and compile again.

Comment: You are right. The problem lies at another point. I edited my question accordingly.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This seems simpler:

```
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@Book{elvis,
    author = "Elvis Presley",
    title = "Turn Me One More Time",
    publisher = "Jail House Books",
    year = 1963,
}
\end{filecontents}
\documentclass{article}
\bibliographystyle{plain}

\usepackage{bibentry}
\makeatletter\let\saved@bibitem\@bibitem\makeatother
\usepackage{hyperref}
\makeatletter\let\@bibitem\saved@bibitem\makeatother

\begin{document}
\nobibliography*
\bibentry{elvis}
\nobibliography{\jobname}
\end{document}
```

The following shows how to integrate `elsarticle-harv.bst`

```
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@Book{elvis,
    author = "Elvis Presley",
    title = "Turn Me One More Time",
    publisher = "Jail House Books",
    year = 1963,
}
\end{filecontents}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{elsarticle-harv}

\usepackage{bibentry}
\makeatletter\let\saved@bibitem\@bibitem\makeatother
\usepackage{hyperref}
\makeatletter\let\@bibitem\saved@bibitem\makeatother

\begin{document}
\nobibliography*
\bibentry{elvis}
\nobibliography{\jobname}       % comment out when using the workaround
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. This is surely simpler than my given code. Unfortunately, I just realized, the actual problem lies with the bibliographystyle. i edites my question accordingly.

Comment: @meep.meep The `elsarticle-harv.bst` style requires the `natbib` package (I guess that `elsart-harv` is an obsolete version). I added a working version with the more modern style.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Once for calling my attention to the never version and for the solution. I really was a blokhead on this one. I actually know about the need for `natbib`, but it slipped my mind here.

Comment: I had a similar problem. I changed the style to plain and I still get the error. pdflatex compiles fine the first time, bibtex compiles fine too. The second time I run pdflatex I get the error.
I am using the splitbib package. Any ideas?

Comment: @fiacobelli I guess that a new question is in order, with a M(non)WE.

Comment: Just came across this myself without an embedded bib file though. I'm new to latex, but what is the actual reason for this bug? To describe a workaround like the document does w/out reason/symptom is not helpful. It was a very frustrating process figuring out why. Are there idiomatic ways to debug such conflicts? Thanks.

Comment: @nlucaroni This workaround disables any trick `hyperref` is doing to `\@bibitem`, which is redefined by `bibentry` in a way that seems to displease `hyperref`.