# Hyperref, bibentry & natbib conflict - incorrect hyperlink

Tags: hyperref, natbib, bibentry

## Problem

I want to cite references in text as well as quote the entire entry plus have a reference list at the end. For this I use `hyperref`, `bibentry` and `natbib`. I've taken as inspiration [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/65348/clash-between-bibentry-and-hyperref-with-bibstyle-elsart-harv). The only difference is that I want to include a reference list as well.

The problem is that the hyperlink points to the `\bibentry` rather than the entry in the reference.

## MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{abbrvnat}

\usepackage{bibentry}
\makeatletter\let\saved@bibitem\@bibitem\makeatother
\usepackage{hyperref}
\makeatletter\let\@bibitem\saved@bibitem\makeatother

\begin{document}
\nobibliography*
Here is a citation \citet{elvis}
%\newpage %uncomment this line and the line below eliminates error but hyperlink still points to \bibentry

Here is the full entry \bibentry{elvis}
%\newpage %uncomment this line 

\bibliography{bibliography}
\end{document}
```

The bib file, bibliography.bib

```
@Book{elvis,
    author = "Elvis Presley",
    title = "Turn Me One More Time",
    publisher = "Jail House Books",
    year = 1963,
}
```

## Warning

The above code gives a warning:

```
destination with the same identifier (name{cite.elvis}) has been already used, duplicate ignored
```

## Solution?

- Interestingly, adding `\newpage`s to split up the `\citet` and `\bibentry` onto separate pages eliminates the warning but the hyperlinking is still wrong.
- Removing `natbib` but again hyperlinking does not work.

Does anybody have any ideas how I can solve this problem?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Wrap the `\bibentry` in `NoHyper`s i.e.

```
\begin{NoHyper}\bibentry{elvis}\end{NoHyper}
```

The hyperlink now points to the correct entry in the references.

Comment: Do you know if there is a way to avoid the hyperlink to point to the reference (and not to the bibentry) and to have an hyperlink in the bibentry itself (for example an url for the preprint)? Thank you in advance for your answer. -Pierre

Comment: This does indeed fix the internal document link, but if there is a hyperlink in the bibliography entry itself, it is not hyperlinked anymore, unfortunately. A way to have both would be brilliant.

Comment: this is the only answer that fixes my problem of aligning references in a tabular.

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/561286/223853 for an answer that avoids hyperlinking to the bibentry, but allows the hyperlinking of URLs inside the bibtentry.

Answer (score 2):

I'd add this to the top answer's comment thread, but I do not yet have the requisite reputation for commenting. With regard to [rubenvb](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/174/rubenvb)'s request in response to wrapping `\bibentry` in a `NoHyper` environment:

> This does indeed fix the internal document link, but if there is a hyperlink in the bibliography entry itself, it is not hyperlinked anymore, unfortunately. A way to have both would be brilliant.

You can eschew `NoHyper` for a simple solution to correctly hyperlink citations to their corresponding non-`\bibentry` reference items (while maintaining existing hyperlinks within the `\bibentry` like URLs):

In your `.bib` file (or if you've defined your bibliographic entries in your preamble), duplicate those references in full and add some differentiating text in the citekey. I like to add `-in` to the end of the citekeys I'll use for `\bibentry` items, since they'll be incorporated `-in` the text. Then, add the [`multibib` environment](https://www.sys.kth.se/docs/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/multibib/multibib.sty) to your `.tex` file [as described in this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/274009/166676). If you try to use `multibib` without duplicating the `.bib` entry of interest, citations will still jump to `\bibentry` instead of your bibliography.

### MWE

#### Broken hyperlinks

`test.bib` file:

```
@article{Lee:2011ct,
author = {Lee, Hun and Lee, Kangsun and Ahn, Byungwook and Xu, Jing and Xu, Linfeng and Oh, Kwang W},
title = {{A new fabrication process for uniform SU-8 thick photoresist structures by simultaneously removing edge bead and air bubbles}},
journal = {Journal of Micromechanics and Microengineering},
year = {2011},
volume = {21},
number = {12},
pages = {125006--9},
month = nov,
doi = {10.1088/0960-1317/21/12/125006},
read = {Yes},
date-added = {2018-06-21T17:15:45GMT},
url = {http://stacks.iop.org/0960-1317/21/i=12/a=125006?key=crossref.dabe730af97ae5fbb7d5b6bb62b8eb90}}
```

`test.tex` file:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{bibentry}

\begin{document}
\nobibliography*

Here is a citation \citet{Lee:2011ct}

Here is the full entry \bibentry{Lee:2011ct}

\newpage

\bibliography{test}
\bibliographystyle{abbrvnat}

\end{document}
```

With this, we'll see improper hyperlinking from the first instance of `\citet` to the `\bibentry` (instead of the `References` section on the next page).

#### Fixed hyperlinks

This is easily resolved by duplicating and modifying our `.bib` item that we want to include as a `\bibentry` and adjusting the `.tex` file:

`test.bib` file:

```
@article{Lee:2011ct,
author = {Lee, Hun and Lee, Kangsun and Ahn, Byungwook and Xu, Jing and Xu, Linfeng and Oh, Kwang W},
title = {{A new fabrication process for uniform SU-8 thick photoresist structures by simultaneously removing edge bead and air bubbles}},
journal = {Journal of Micromechanics and Microengineering},
year = {2011},
volume = {21},
number = {12},
pages = {125006--9},
month = nov,
doi = {10.1088/0960-1317/21/12/125006},
read = {Yes},
date-added = {2018-06-21T17:15:45GMT},
url = {http://stacks.iop.org/0960-1317/21/i=12/a=125006?key=crossref.dabe730af97ae5fbb7d5b6bb62b8eb90}}

@article{Lee:2011ct-in,
author = {Lee, Hun and Lee, Kangsun and Ahn, Byungwook and Xu, Jing and Xu, Linfeng and Oh, Kwang W},
title = {{A new fabrication process for uniform SU-8 thick photoresist structures by simultaneously removing edge bead and air bubbles}},
journal = {Journal of Micromechanics and Microengineering},
year = {2011},
volume = {21},
number = {12},
pages = {125006--9},
month = nov,
doi = {10.1088/0960-1317/21/12/125006},
read = {Yes},
date-added = {2018-06-21T17:15:45GMT},
url = {http://stacks.iop.org/0960-1317/21/i=12/a=125006?key=crossref.dabe730af97ae5fbb7d5b6bb62b8eb90}}
```

`test.tex` file:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{bibentry}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{multibib}
\newcites{q}{References}

\begin{document}
\nobibliography*

Here is a citation \citetq{Lee:2011ct}

Here is the full entry \bibentry{Lee:2011ct-in}

\newpage

\bibliographystyleq{abbrvnat}
\bibliographyq{test.bib}
\bibliographystyle{abbrvnat}
\nobibliography{test.bib}

\end{document}
```

This produces your desired output: the in-text citation links to the bibliography, and the URL in the `\bibentry` item is still functional without being hyperlinked to the in-text citation. To compile this `.tex` file, use the following build order:

```
pdflatex test.tex
bibtex q
bibtex test
pdflatex test
pdflatex test
```

I know it's been almost six years since this was first asked, but I recently found this solution useful and wanted it to be available for anyone else who might come across this thread.

Answer (score 1):

What also helps is to use BOTH packages:
natbib AND bibentry.

The issue is then ressolved for me.

Thus, make use of:

```
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{bibentry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{hyperref}
```

Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

You can redefine `\bibentry` to omit its internal hyperlinking:

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\bibentry}[1]{\nocite{#1}{\frenchspacing\@nameuse{BR@r@#1\@extra@b@citeb}}}
\makeatother
```