# How to deal with % sign in url when using hyperref and bibentry

Tags: bibtex, hyperref, urls, bibentry

In few of my citations I have a % sign in the url, which gives a problem when I use the `bibentry` environment (Paragraph ended before \BR@c@bibitem was complete). How can I deal with the % sign? Without the reference containing the % in the url everything works fine. Also without using the `bibentry` the % gives no problem. the % sign gives also no problem using a different bibliography stile as unsrt, which is not using the url information (which I don't want to do). (The bibliography style statto can be found [here](http://www.jorrit.org/typo3/uploads/media/statto.bst), same problem occurs using `plainnat`). Not using `\begin{NoHyper}\bibentry{goossens93}\end{NoHyper}` would be preferred to hyperlink the reference to the website, but I don't know if this would be possible at all.

```
    \begin{filecontents}{mytestbib.bib}
@book{goossens93,
    author = "Frank Mittelbach and Michel Goossens  and Johannes Braams and David Carlisle  and Chris Rowley",
    title = "The {LaTeX} Companion",
    year = "1993",
    publisher = "Addison-Wesley",
    address = "Reading, Massachusetts"
}

@BOOK{Kymissis__2009,
  title = {Organic Field Effect Transistors - Theory, Fabrication and Characterization},
  publisher = {Springer},
  year = {2009},
  author = {Kymissis, Ioannis},
  abstract = {Organic Field Effect Transistors discusses the fundamental mechanisms
    that apply to {OFETs} fabrication, operation, and characterization.
    This unique book presents the state-of-the-art in organic field effect
    transistors ({OFETs)} with ...},
  isbn = {9780387921341},
  keywords = {Circuits and Systems, Fabrication and Characterization, Organic Chemistry,
    Organic Field Effect Transistors - Theory, Technology \& Engineering
    / Engineering (General)},
  language = {English},
  shorttitle = {Organic Field Effect Transistors},
  timestamp = {2013.10.07},
  url = {http://www.springer.com/engineering/circuits+%26+systems/book/978-0-387-92133-4}
}

\end{filecontents}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[pdftex]{hyperref}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{bibentry}
\nobibliography*


\begin{document}

A full in-text cite of
\begin{NoHyper}\bibentry{goossens93}\end{NoHyper}.

A regular citation of \cite{goossens93}.

Problematic cite \cite{Kymissis__2009}


\bibliographystyle{statto}
\bibliography{mytestbib}

\end{document}
```

Comment: escaping gives still the same problem. So it could be, that the problem is elsewhere. This is however one of 4 citations which gives problems and all hat % signs in the url

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This seems to work: the `\BR@c@bibitem` macro is patched to change the category code of `%` before grabbing its argument.

```
\begin{filecontents}{mytestbib.bib}

@book{goossens93,
  author = {Frank Mittelbach and Michel Goossens and Johannes Braams
            and David Carlisle and Chris Rowley},
  title = {The {LaTeX} Companion},
  year = {1993},
  publisher = {Addison-Wesley},
  address = {Reading, Massachusetts},
}

@BOOK{Kymissis__2009,
  title = {Organic Field Effect Transistors - Theory, Fabrication and Characterization},
  publisher = {Springer},
  year = {2009},
  author = {Kymissis, Ioannis},
  abstract = {Organic Field Effect Transistors discusses the fundamental mechanisms
    that apply to {OFETs} fabrication, operation, and characterization.
    This unique book presents the state-of-the-art in organic field effect
    transistors ({OFETs)} with ...},
  file = {Snapshot:C:\Documents and Settings\haehlen_t\My Documents\Papers\Zotero\storage\KV3VMKEJ\978-0-387-92133-4.html:text/html},
  isbn = {9780387921341},
  keywords = {Circuits and Systems, Fabrication and Characterization, Organic Chemistry,
    Organic Field Effect Transistors - Theory, Technology \& Engineering
    / Engineering (General)},
  language = {English},
  owner = {haehlen_t},
  shorttitle = {Organic Field Effect Transistors},
  timestamp = {2013.10.07},
  url = {http://www.springer.com/engineering/circuits+%26+systems/book/978-0-387-92133-4}
}

\end{filecontents}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{bibentry}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\let\ORIG@BR@c@bibitem\BR@c@bibitem
\apptocmd\ORIG@BR@c@bibitem{\endgroup}{}{}
\def\BR@c@bibitem{\begingroup\catcode`\%=12 \ORIG@BR@c@bibitem}
\makeatother
\nobibliography*


\begin{document}

A full in-text cite of
\begin{NoHyper}\bibentry{goossens93}\end{NoHyper}.

A regular citation of \cite{goossens93}.

Problematic cite \cite{Kymissis__2009}

\begin{NoHyper}\bibentry{Kymissis__2009}\end{NoHyper}

\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\bibliography{mytestbib}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Some words about the trick.

The `bibentry` package redefines `\bibitem` to use the internal macro `\BR@c@bibitem` which basically grabs the argument of `\bibitem` and then all that comes up to the first blank line as its second argument. The presence of `%` in the argument of `\url` confuses the parser which is unable to see the closing brace, which is behind the `%`.

Thus we redefine the macro to do the work in two stages:

1. it opens a group;
2. inside this group it sets the category code of `%` to 12, making it a printable character;
3. calls `\ORIG@BR@c@bibitem`

The final macro is basically a copy of the original `\BR@c@bibitem`, with the only change that at the end of its work it issues the `\endgroup` that balances the `\begingroup` issued by (the new) `\BR@c@bibitem`.

Comment: Could you explain what the following part exactly does? 
    `\usepackage{etoolbox}
    \makeatletter
\let\ORIG@BR@c@bibitem\BR@c@bibitem
    \apptocmd\ORIG@BR@c@bibitem{\endgroup}{}{}
    \def\BR@c@bibitem{\begingroup\catcode``\%=12       \ORIG@BR@c@bibitem}
    \makeatother`

Comment: Thanks. I guess altering in a similar way  to not need the `\begin{NoHyper}....\end{NoHyper}` in order to have the hyperlink in the `bibentry` is not possible? Or is it worth posting a separate question with this?

Comment: @user2758804 If I remove the `NoHyper` environment, I get a duplicate entry warning.

Comment: Yes this is the problem. I found just this [solution](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/81937/hyperref-bibentry-natbib-conflict-incorrect-hyperlink) and was wondering if it can be avoided without excluding the hyperlink completely

Comment: @user2758804 We need Heiko for this. ;-)

Comment: I guess I should then open a new question for this specific problem.