# Workaround for bibentry when using natbib and pagebackref

Tags: natbib, back-referencing, bibentry

I am using natbib and hyperref's pagebackref. Now I also wanted to use bibentry, but I get the error message

> File ended while scanning use of \BR@c@bibitem. \par \nobibliography*
>   % For bibentry commands

It seems this is an old bug, as described in https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/comp.text.tex/ZJCRwBhOc5s.

Is there a **workaround** so that I can add some full references in my text (as with bibentry) but can keep my remaining setup as is, especially keep using natbib and hyperrefs?

---

Details about relevant parts of my setup:

```
\usepackage[square]{natbib} %citation style
\usepackage{bibentry}
\usepackage[plainpages=false,
            pdftex,
            pagebackref,
            bookmarks,
            pdfstartview=FitV,
            pdfpagelabels,
            pdfpagemode=UseNone,
        a4paper=false,
        setpagesize=false]{hyperref}


\begin{document}
  \include{introduction}
  \backmatter 
  \hbadness=2000
  \bibliographystyle{plainnat}
  \bibliography{davef,diss}
  \printindex
\end{document}
```

and in introduction, I use

```
\nobibliography{davef,diss}
\bibentry{foo}
```

Comment: Maybe this is the same as http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/141247/how-to-deal-with-sign-in-url-when-using-hyperref-and-bibentry, can you check?

Comment: Good idea (+1), unfortunately, it's not the same problem: unsrt style does not fix the problem. But omitting pagebackref does. I do want to use pagebackref, however.

Comment: You should present a minimal example with a bib entry giving the problem.