# Problem of duplicate identifier when using bibentry and hyperref

Tags: bibtex, hyperref, bibentry

I want to used `\bibentry`and `hyperref` in my document. However when I use it as in the sample below I get the error

> destination with the same identifier (name{cite.Duhm_AppliedPhysicsLetters_2009}) has been already used, dublicate ignored

I found  [this work around](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/81937/hyperref-bibentry-natbib-conflict-incorrect-hyperlink) which works well (commented version in the sample below). However, the bibliography style [statto](http://www.jorrit.org/typo3/uploads/media/statto.bst), hyperlinks the title to the respective url, which I would like to keep also in the `bibentry` (I don't care if there is a hyperlink to the item in the bibliography itself). Is there a solution for this problem, which is not a simple work around which completely ignores the hyperlink?

```
\begin{filecontents}{mytestbib.bib}

@ARTICLE{Duhm_AppliedPhysicsLetters_2009,
  author = {Duhm, Steffen and Salzmann, Ingo and BroÌˆker, Benjamin and Glowatzki,
    Hendrik and Johnson, Robert L. and Koch, Norbert},
  title = {Interdiffusion of molecular acceptors through organic layers to metal
    substrates mimics doping-related energy level shifts},
  journal = {Applied Physics Letters},
  year = {2009},
  volume = {95},
  pages = {093305},
  doi = {10.1063/1.3213547},
  issn = {00036951},
  url = {http://link.aip.org/link/APPLAB/v95/i9/p093305/s1&Agg=doi},
  urldate = {2011-11-05}
}


\end{filecontents}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage[pdftex]{hyperref}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{bibentry}
\makeatother \nobibliography*


\begin{document}

A full in-text cite of
%\begin{NoHyper}\bibentry{Duhm_AppliedPhysicsLetters_2009}\end{NoHyper}.
\bibentry{Duhm_AppliedPhysicsLetters_2009}.

A regular citation  \cite{Duhm_AppliedPhysicsLetters_2009}.


\bibliographystyle{statto}
\bibliography{mytestbib}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can redefine the `\bibentry` command so it does not create a hyperref target by adding

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\bibentry[1]{\nocite{#1}{\frenchspacing
     \@nameuse{BR@r@#1\@extra@b@citeb}}}
\makeatother
```

to your preamble.

E.g. your example (with `natbib` options added from your commet so it does not throw an error); the in text ordinary citation now links to the bibliography:

[image: Sample output]

```
\begin{filecontents}{mytestbib.bib}

@ARTICLE{Duhm_AppliedPhysicsLetters_2009,
  author = {Duhm, Steffen and Salzmann, Ingo and BroÌˆker, Benjamin and Glowatzki,
    Hendrik and Johnson, Robert L. and Koch, Norbert},
  title = {Interdiffusion of molecular acceptors through organic layers to metal
    substrates mimics doping-related energy level shifts},
  journal = {Applied Physics Letters},
  year = {2009},
  volume = {95},
  pages = {093305},
  doi = {10.1063/1.3213547},
  issn = {00036951},
  url = {http://link.aip.org/link/APPLAB/v95/i9/p093305/s1&Agg=doi},
  urldate = {2011-11-05}
}


\end{filecontents}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage[square, sort&compress, numbers]{natbib}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{bibentry}
\usepackage[pdftex]{hyperref}

\nobibliography*

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\bibentry[1]{\nocite{#1}{\frenchspacing
     \@nameuse{BR@r@#1\@extra@b@citeb}}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

A full in-text cite of
\bibentry{Duhm_AppliedPhysicsLetters_2009}.

A regular citation  \cite{Duhm_AppliedPhysicsLetters_2009}.


\bibliographystyle{statto}
\bibliography{mytestbib}

\end{document}
```

The new definition is just the code from `bibentry.sty`, i.e.

```
\newcommand\bibentry[1]{\nocite{#1}{\frenchspacing
     \hyper@natanchorstart{#1\@extra@b@citeb}%
     \@nameuse{BR@r@#1\@extra@b@citeb}\hyper@natanchorend}}
```

with the hyperref anchor start/end commands removed.

Comment: I added your solution to my file and it works fine. I seems that using `\usepackage[square, sort&compress, numbers]{natbib}` (instead of just `natbib`only) as I have it in my file gives no error. Could you quickly explain the different elements you use in the solution?

Comment: @user2758804 natbib options now added to my code.  Short explanation of where the command comes from added.