# How to use BibTeX for putting a nice publication list in resume with document class (res.cls)

Tags: bibtex, resume, cv

I am trying to put a publication list using BibTex into resume. But I do not know why it does not compile?. Here is my effort.

Following is the code that I want to use BibTex for its publication list

```
   % LaTeX file for resume 
% This file uses the resume document class (res.cls)

\documentclass{res} 
\usepackage{bibentry}
%\usepackage{helvetica} % uses helvetica postscript font (download helvetica.sty)
%\usepackage{newcent}   % uses new century schoolbook postscript font 
\newsectionwidth{0pt}  % So the text is not indented under section headings
\usepackage{fancyhdr}  % use this package to get a 2 line header
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt} % suppress line drawn by default by fancyhdr
\setlength{\headheight}{24pt} % allow room for 2-line header
\setlength{\headsep}{24pt}  % space between header and text
\setlength{\headheight}{24pt} % allow room for 2-line header
\pagestyle{fancy}     % set pagestyle for document
\rhead{ {\it J. Razi}\\{\it p. \thepage} } % put text in header (right side)
\cfooJ. Razit{}                                     % the foot is empty
\topmargin=-0.5in % start text higher on the page

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty} % this page has no header  
\name{Jack Razi\\[12pt]}% the \\[12pt] adds a blank line after name

\address{{}\\
{\bf School Address} \\ {NDT Group }\\Department of Civil Engineering and Engineering mechanics\\
  University of Arizona \\   Tucson, AZ 85719 \\ (520) 258-1762}    


\begin{resume}

\section{\centerline{OBJECTIVE}}
\vspace{8pt} % provide vertical space between section title and contents
Applying for Whitenack, Dr. Russell D. Scholarship

\vspace{0.2in}
\section{\centerline{EDUCATION}} 
\vspace{8pt} 
{\sl Doctor of Philosophy}, Engineering mechanics\\
University of Arizona, Tucson, Arizona \hspace{0.2in}  GPA 3.5 \hfill May 2017 \\
Dissertation - Peridynamic model for fatigue crack growth\\
Advisor : Prof. Tribikram Kundu (University of California, Los Angles, 1983)

{\sl Master of Science}, Mechanical and Materials Engineering \\
National University of Malaysia, Bangi, Selangore \hspace{0.2in}  GPA 4.00 \hfill November 2011 \\
THESIS - Fatigue crack failure of metallic components under variable amplitude loadings\\
 Advisor : Prof Nik Abdullah (Tech. University Berlin, Germany, 1991)\\

{\sl Bachelor of Science}, Mechanical Engineering - Solid mechanics \\ % \sl will be bold italic in
                     % New Century Schoolbook (or
                     % any postscript font) and
                     % just slanted in Computer
                     % Modern (default) font
                     Top 3.5\%,  out of 450,000 applicants in University Entrance National Exam (2002) \\
Tehran, Iran (Islamic Republic of)      \hfill    February 2007

\vspace{0.2in} 
\section{\centerline{PROFESSIONAL EXPERIENCE}} 
\vspace{8pt}
{\sl Bahman (Mazda motor) Co} \hfill        2007-2009 \\
Product Engineering Devision, Tehran, Iran       \hfill   (Product Engineer)

   \begin{itemize} \itemsep -2pt % reduce space between items
   \item  Working with a core team and internal and external customers to improve design, simulation, processing, and experimental techniques. 
   \item Developed and carried out simulation and experiments to investigate failure modes in components. 
  \item  Developed a full finite element analysis of the radiator shroud with ANSYS in order to find the weakest areas. Fatigue analysis was conducted and a new design was proposed.
  \end{itemize}

{\sl Iran Air} \hfill  May-Aug 2006 \\
Mechanical workshops, Engineering \& Maintenance Department, Tehran, Iran \hfill (Engineering Intern)
  \begin{itemize}
  \item  Technical courses including knowledge and practical training facilitated by Mechanical Workshops. 
 \end{itemize}

{\sl Bahman Co } \hfill  May-Aug 2005 \\
R\&D Devison, Tehran, Iran \hfill (Engineering Intern)
  \begin{itemize}
  \item  Accurate use of a coordinate measuring machine (CMM with ROMER) 
 \end{itemize}

\newpage

\vspace{0.2in} 
\section{\centerline{ COMPUTING SKILLS }}
\vspace{8pt} 
Experienced in ANSYS,  Abaqus,  Matlab,  Fortran, LaTeX



\vspace{0.2in} 
\section{\centerline{PUBLICATIONS}} 
\vspace{15pt}

J. Razi, T. Kundu, Crack propagation modeling using Peridynamic theory, Health Monitoring of Structural and Biological Systems X, SPIE 2016; Las Vegas; United States\

J. Razi, T. Kundu, Peridynamic modeling for mortar and shape memory alloy mix, Health Monitoring of Structural and Biological Systems X,SPIE 2016; Las Vegas; United States\



\newpage
\vspace{0.2in} 
\section{\centerline{MEMBERSHIPS}} 
\vspace{-5pt} % reduce space between section title and contents
\begin{center}
      American Society of Mechanical Engineering (ASME) \\
       International Society of Optical Engineering (SPIE) \\ 

 \end{center}
 \vspace{0.2in}
\section{\centerline{HONORS}} 
\vspace{-5pt}
\begin{center}

  Research Assistant, University of Arizona (Aug 2013 - May2016)  \\
                  Teaching Assistant, University of Arizona (Aug 2013 - May 2015) \\
              Science Foundation of Ireland Fellowship (Aug 2012 - July 2013) \\
              (SFI Fellowship Award to be a highly significant accomplishment) \\
              Research honorarium, University of Malaya (March 2012 - July 2012)\\
              Graduate Research Assistant, National University of Malaysia (Aug 2009 - March 2012)

\end{center}

\vspace{0.2in}
\section{\centerline{INTERESTS}} 
\vspace{-5pt} 
\begin{center}
Swimming, Traveling 
\end{center} 

 \nobibliography{ref}
  \bibliographystyle{unsrt}

  \section*{Publications}
  \begin{enumerate}
    \item \bibentry{knuth1986}
    \item \bibentry{lamport1986}
  \end{enumerate}



\end{resume} 
\end{document}
```

Comment: Kurt's answers seem to give what the desired result. I've added another option using `bibentry` in my answer below.

Comment: This isn't what you are asking but, and hear me out, maybe you should just link to your ORCID publications list. If you are applying for a very academic job or a grant they usually ask you to attach a list of your five most relevant publications anyway. In a separate document. I have mine in the homepage part of the modernCV package / template.

Answer (score 31):

You can use the `bibentry` package with `\nobibliography`. Here is a MWE with references stored in `ref.bib` file:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{bibentry}
\begin{document}
  \nobibliography{ref}
  \bibliographystyle{unsrt}

  \section*{Publications}
  \begin{enumerate}
    \item \bibentry{knuth1986}
    \item \bibentry{lamport1986}
  \end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @Mohammad I'm not an expert on the inner workings of TeX, but I think aux files are part of the compilation process and not class specific.

Comment: @Mohammad I have added the [`res.cls`](https://www.math.nyu.edu/student_resources/res.cls) class and it seems to work fine for bilbliography. Check the link again.

Comment: @Mohammad Sorry, I didn't see your comment earlier. I have copied your code and replaced my code (on Sharelatex link) with yours. It works find except a `\cfootJ` command. I'm not sure if I'm using the same `res.cls` file as yours.

Comment: @Mohammad I used your code as is, I didn't modify it, just copied and pasted it to ShareLaTeX (which I use because I don't have TeX installed on my machine). Good luck!

Comment: Could you include your .bib file ? I get a `LaTeX Error: Lonely \item--perhaps a missing list environment.`

Comment: not exactly my case, this one is more relevant https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/44589/how-to-split-bibliography-for-different-sections

Comment: adding \usepackage{natbib} fixed the "Lonely \item" error.

Comment: also, when used with other .bst files, such as utphys, natbib needs to be loaded with the following params: \usepackage[square,sort,comma,numbers]{natbib}. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/75015/171313

Comment: Adding \usepackage{natbib} also fixed a half page blank space that I had.

Comment: Adding `\usepackage[square,sort,comma,numbers]{natbib}` under `\usepackage{bibentry}` fixed the `LaTeX Error: Lonely \item--perhaps a missing list environment` that pops up on the `.bbl` file that is autogenerated. `\usepackage{natbib}` hit a different error and was insufficient for me.

Answer (score 5):

I put together a minimal working example (MWE) for generating a list of publications (e.g. for an academic cv) from Bibtex entries that additionally enables splitting publications into different sections (peer-reviewed, conference abstracts, ...) as well as adding links to the pdf and using your favourite citation style.

The github repo can be found here: https://github.com/rgeirhos/academic-cv-publications, it contains some additional information and a minimal cv.

The LaTeX code is here:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}

%COMPILING: IMPORTANT INFORMATION
% You'll need to generate a .bbl file from
% the .bib file first, otherwise the publications
% will not show up in the cv.

% in TeXstudio, this means
% 1. F1 or F6 for usual compiling (generate .aux)
% 1. F8 for bibliography compiling (generate .bbl)
% 2. F1 or F6 for usual compiling once more(generate .pdf)

% use your favourite citation style here
\usepackage{apacite}

\usepackage[left=2.5cm,right=2.5cm,top=1.5cm,bottom=2.5cm]{geometry}


% as bibentry and hyperref clash in some cases, this is a workaround
% as suggested by the following two links:
%https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/227933/using-bibentry-to-cite-in-text-reference-with-apacite
% and
%https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/65348/clash-between-bibentry-and-hyperref-with-bibstyle-elsart-harv/65401#65401
\usepackage{bibentry}
\makeatletter\let\saved@bibitem\@bibitem\makeatother
\usepackage[colorlinks=true]{hyperref}
\makeatletter\let\@bibitem\saved@bibitem\makeatother


% hanging publications: 1st line starts at beginning of line, 
% further lines are placed a bit to the right
\usepackage{hanging}
\newcommand\publication[1]{%
    \smallskip\par\hangpara{1.5em}{1}\bibentry{#1}\smallskip
}


\begin{document}

    % bibliography
    \nobibliography{publications.bib}
    \bibliographystyle{apacite} 

    \section*{Publications} 

    % optional: split into different subsections for
    % peer-reviewed articles, conference abstracts, ...

    % example with links
    \publication{Geirhos2017}
        (\href{https://arxiv.org/abs/1706.06969}{link}, \href{https://arxiv.org/pdf/1706.06969.pdf}{pdf}, \href{https://github.com/rgeirhos/object-recognition}{data and materials})

    % example without links
    \publication{Knuth1998}

    % the cumbersome way
%   \hangpara{1.5em}{1}Knuth, D. E. (1998). 
%   \textit{The art of computer programming: sorting and searching} (Vol. 3). Pearson Education.

\end{document}
```

With the following .bib file entries (should be named publications.bib):

```
@article{Geirhos2017,
  title={Comparing deep neural networks against humans: object recognition when the signal gets weaker},
  author={Geirhos, Robert and Janssen, David HJ and Sch{\"u}tt, Heiko H and Rauber, Jonas and Bethge, Matthias and Wichmann, Felix A},
  journal={arXiv preprint arXiv:1706.06969},
  year={2017}}

@book{Knuth1998,
  title={The art of computer programming: sorting and searching},
  author={Knuth, Donald Ervin},
  volume={3},
  year={1998},
  publisher={Pearson Education}}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! This does not really answer the question in its current state. Answers in this network should be self-contained (not link-only) and in this case clearly contain the code (with some explanations).

Comment: Thanks @TeXnician for pointing this out, I updated my answer and included the code (with comments).

Comment: I tried this but I am getting `bibtex returned exit code 1` any suggestion?

Comment: @zhk have you successfully generated a .bbl file from the .bib file?

Comment: @Ergee Problem solved. Thx