# Sorting bibliography in order of appearance without Bibtex

Tags: bibliographies

Is there a way to sort bibliography in order of appearance without Bibtex? I am using the following format for the bibliography

```
\begin{thebibliography}{}
\bibitem{ref1}{reference1}
\bibitem{re2} {reference2}
\end{thebibliography}
```

I tried using `\bibliographystyle{unsrt}` but it had no effect.

Comment: `bibtex` is what does the sorting. If you are doing a manual bibliography, you have to sort it as you want manually too. Is there a reason you don't want to use `bibtex`?

Comment: Simple answer: No. See https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Manually_Managing_References

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually BibTeX takes care of sorting your bibliography. And BibTeX is pretty good at that, so I strongly suggest you let BibTeX sort your bibliography. If you use `.bib` files it is much easier to re-use your bibliographic data should you have to change the style.

In case of cite-order sorting (`unsrt`), you can get `thebibliography` To sort the bibliography for you automatically with some low-level hacking if you additionally accept a slight change in the syntax of `\bibitem`.

Normally `\bibitem` works like `\item` and takes only one argument (the entry key) and an optional argument (the fixed label), the entry data itself is not an argument of `\bibitem`. For the code below to work the entry data needs to be an argument of `\bibitem`. That means that entries in `thebibliography` can't look like

```
\bibitem{foo} Lorem Ipsum.
\bibitem[bar]{bar} Dolor sit amet.
```

they must look like

```
\bibitem{foo}{Lorem Ipsum.}
\bibitem[bar]{bar}{Dolor sit amet.}
```

Since you have these braces in your question already, I trust this is not a deal-breaker for you.

You may have to run LaTeX three times until all citation labels are resolved correctly, but you should get re-run warnings when a further run is required.

The main idea is that whenever you `\cite` an entry LaTeX writes the key to a list of all entry keys. This is implemented via the `\citation` macro in the `.aux` file, which means that the complete citation order is available at the beginning of the document, but requires two LaTeX runs.

`thebibliography` works in two steps, first it just collects all entries and their data (that's why we need the additional argument, so `\bibitem` can grab the data), then in a second step it prints the entries in the order given by the entry list.

The code is based on the standard definitions of `\citation` and `\bibitem` from the LaTeX kernel and `thebibliography` from `article.cls`. For a different document class or packages like `cite` or `natbib` the definitions may have to be tweaked a bit (the code is compatible with `hyperref` already, though).

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
%\usepackage{hyperref}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\lodbib@citeorder}{}
\newcommand*{\lodbib@notcited}{}% catch entries that were not cited

% macro in aux file
\def\citation{%
  \forcsvlist{\citation@i}}

\def\citation@i#1{%
  \ifinlist{#1}{\lodbib@citeorder}
    {}
    {\listxadd{\lodbib@citeorder}{#1}}}

\let\ltxorig@lbibitem\@lbibitem
\let\ltxorig@bibitem\@bibitem

% save bibitems
\def\@lbibitem[#1]#2#3{%
  \csdef{lodbib@savedlabel@#2}{#1}%
  \@bibitem{#2}{#3}}

\def\@bibitem#1#2{%
  \xifinlist{#1}{\lodbib@citeorder}
    {}
    {\listadd{\lodbib@notcited}{#1}}%
  \csdef{lodbib@savedentry@#1}{#2}}

\renewenvironment{thebibliography}[1]
     {\settowidth\labelwidth{\@biblabel{#1}}}
     {\def\@noitemerr
       {\@latex@warning{Empty `thebibliography' environment}}%
      \section*{\refname}%
      \@mkboth{\MakeUppercase\refname}{\MakeUppercase\refname}%
      \list{\@biblabel{\@arabic\c@enumiv}}%
           {\leftmargin\labelwidth
            \advance\leftmargin\labelsep
            \@openbib@code
            \usecounter{enumiv}%
            \let\p@enumiv\@empty
            \renewcommand\theenumiv{\@arabic\c@enumiv}}%
      \sloppy
      \clubpenalty4000
      \@clubpenalty \clubpenalty
      \widowpenalty4000%
      \sfcode`\.\@m
      \lodbib@biblistloop
      \endlist}

\def\lodbib@biblistloop{%
  \forlistloop{\lodbib@bibitem}{\lodbib@citeorder}%
  \ifdefvoid{\lodbib@notcited}
    {}
    {\forlistloop{\lodbib@bibitem}{\lodbib@notcited}}}

\def\lodbib@bibitem#1{%
  \ifcsundef{lodbib@savedlabel@#1}
    {\ltxorig@bibitem{#1}}
    {\ltxorig@lbibitem[\csuse{lodbib@savedlabel@#1}]{#1}}%
  \csuse{lodbib@savedentry@#1}}
\makeatother


\begin{document}
\cite{ref2} and \cite{ref3} and \cite{ref1}

\begin{thebibliography}{C}
\bibitem{ref1}{AAAA}
\bibitem{ref2}{BBBB}
\bibitem[C]{ref3}{CCCC}
\bibitem{ref4}{DDDD}
\end{thebibliography}

\cite{ref2}
\end{document}
```

[image: Citations: "[1] and [C] and [2]", bibliography: "[1] BBBB//[C] CCCC//[2] AAAA//[3] DDDD"]

*edit:* Fix for `cite` package, see [Multiple Reference Citation in order of appearance without Bibtex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/461829/35864).

Comment: This actually worked. However I got an error which, when I searched, seemed like a [Clash between bibentry and hyperref with bibstyle elsart-harv](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/65401/172097). I used the same solution and it's working but clicking the in-text citation takes me to title page instead of the reference. Can that be fixed?

Comment: @Lod What error did you get in what context? The code as posted in the answer worked without errors for me. Please consider adding an example document, a so-called [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864), that reproduces the error.

Comment: @meowe It works without huper links. the error I got was `Lonely \item--perhaps a missing list environment` when compiling and I fixed it by adding `\usepackage{bibentry}
\makeatletter\let\saved@bibitem\@bibitem\makeatother
\usepackage{hyperref}
\makeatletter\let\@bibitem\saved@bibitem\makeatother`
But when I click the green box, it takes me to page one and not the reference in the bibliography.

Comment: @Lod The example still works fine for me when I add `\usepackage{hyperref}` directly after `\usepackage{etoolbox}`. I can not reproduce the error you mention and the links work just fine. Please share a complete example document that reproduces the issue.

Comment: Oh okay, I added it at the end. Thank you it works now!