# Bibtex with no inbuilt arguments

Tags: bibtex

Is there a way to simplify bibtex such that I can decide for myself how each reference shall appear so for example having:

```
@article{Text,
  whatIwanttoappear = {Author, "title", and extra information}
}
```

will simply output

[X] Author, "title", and extra information

so that i don't need to stick to the same style for every source and don't need to use the inbuilt versions. Ie: I want to be able to specify what appears in the {} after whatIwanttoappear such that it appears exactly as it is.

Many thanks.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) A tip: If you indent lines by 4 spaces, they'll be [marked as a code sample](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1192). You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it).

Comment: No, that is not how bibtex works. The whole idea behind bibtex and biblatex is to separate the data and the formatting including what is or is not shown and why.

Comment: You can look for styles and how to style the output, for example here https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/35040/where-can-i-find-collections-of-bibliography-styles

Comment: Hello, the reason I am doing this is because I have a very large reference list, but would like them to be ordered in order of occurrence in the text. It would be easier for me to simply copy the references I have already typed up as they are, than to separate the data out. Does anyone know of a style that can incorporate an indefinite amount of inputs in one line and symbols such as quotation marks?

Comment: This person has found a solution without bibtex to sort items in order of appearance that currently works for me: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/458422/sorting-bibliography-in-order-of-appearance-without-bibtex

Comment: This is quite against the spirit of BibTeX/`biblatex`, but can be done for `biblatex` as explained in https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/438759/35864. It should also be possible for BibTeX, but involves programming in the somewhat arcane `.bst` file language.