# Adding a list of BibTex entries inside a tabular environment

Tags: tables, bibtex, cv

I'm working on my academic CV and was wondering how I might be able to add in a list of publications as BibTex entries inside a tabular environment.

I'm currently using the `longtable` package to write my CV. I've taken a look at some other answers here, and many of them seem to recommend using `multicolumn` and `multirow` commands, but I was wondering if there might be a way to do so without changing the basic framework of my code. And in fact, adding a list-like object into my table in general seems to cause many errors.

Here's a MWE:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,11pt,oneside]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{bibentry}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{kotex}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\newcommand{\MYhref}[3][blue]{\href{#2}{\color{#1}{#3}}}

\usepackage{tgtermes}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{ {images/}}

\usepackage[left=0.75in, right=0.75in, bottom=1in, top=1in]{geometry}

%Changes the page numbers - {arabic}=arabic numerals, {gobble}=no page numbers, {roman}=Roman numerals
\pagenumbering{gobble}


\begin{document}

\noindent \begin{longtable}{@{} l l l}

\noindent  \LARGE{\textbf{John A. Doe}} \\
\vspace{-2ex}
\\\toprule
\normalsize \\

\Large{Contact} & \textbf{Full name} \  John Albert Doe \\
\Large{Information} & \textbf{Email} email1@email.com \\
                    & \indent  \quad  \  email2@email.com \\
                    & \textbf{Mobile} 123456789 \\
                    & \textbf{Address} Home address \\

\\
     
\Large{Research} & \textbf{LaTeX} \\
\Large{Interests} & \indent Stuff. \\
     
\\
     
\Large{Projects} & \\

\Large{Publications}    & \textbf{International} \\
     & \cite{something2020} \\
     & \\
\\

\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

### Edit

Thanks to a comment from @Bernard I changed the environment to `xltabular`. I've also tried to do something as displayed in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/297365/how-to-use-bibtex-for-putting-a-nice-publication-list-in-resume-with-document-cl), but unfortunately I'm still having trouble figuring out how to put the list into the tabular environment rather than as a separate section.

Comment: You can try  the `xltabular` environment, which brings the functionalities of `longtable` to `tabularx`, like this: `\begin{xltabular}{\linewidth}{@{}llX@{}} ... \end{xltabular}`.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I wasn't aware of that environment. Unfortunately I'm not sure how to progress from there. I'll edit in some details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you could use something like:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,11pt,oneside]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{kotex}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{xltabular}

\newcommand{\MYhref}[3][blue]{\href{#2}{\color{#1}{#3}}}

\usepackage{tgtermes}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{ {images/}}

\usepackage[left=0.75in, right=0.75in, bottom=1in, top=1in]{geometry}


%%% hyperref should be last package in preamble, 
%%% to solve lonely \item error see also:
%%% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/65401/134144
\usepackage{bibentry}
\makeatletter\let\saved@bibitem\@bibitem\makeatother
\usepackage{hyperref}
\makeatletter\let\@bibitem\saved@bibitem\makeatother


%Changes the page numbers - {arabic}=arabic numerals, {gobble}=no page numbers, {roman}=Roman numerals
\pagenumbering{gobble}




\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{key,
  author = {Author, A.},
  year = {2001},
  title = {Title},
  publisher = {Publisher},
}
@article{key2,
  author = {Author, A. and Author B. and Author C.},
  year = {2001},
  title = {a very long article title a very long article title},
  journal = {Journal Name},
}
\end{filecontents}

\bibliographystyle{plain}


\begin{document}


\nobibliography{\jobname}

\noindent \begin{xltabular}{\textwidth}{@{} l X l}

\noindent  \LARGE{\textbf{John A. Doe}} \\
\vspace{-2ex}
\\\toprule
\normalsize \\

\Large{Contact} & \textbf{Full name} \  John Albert Doe \\
\Large{Information} & \textbf{Email} email1@email.com \\
                    & \indent  \quad  \  email2@email.com \\
                    & \textbf{Mobile} 123456789 \\
                    & \textbf{Address} Home address \\

\\
     
\Large{Research} & \textbf{LaTeX} \\
\Large{Interests} & \indent Stuff. \\
     
\\
     
\Large{Projects} & \\

\Large{Publications}    & \textbf{International} \\
     & \bibentry{key} \\
     & \bibentry{key2}\\
\\

\end{xltabular}



\end{document}
```

[image]

---

Here is a version with a numbered list:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,11pt,oneside]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{kotex}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{xltabular}

\newcommand{\MYhref}[3][blue]{\href{#2}{\color{#1}{#3}}}

\usepackage{tgtermes}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{ {images/}}

\usepackage[left=0.75in, right=0.75in, bottom=1in, top=1in]{geometry}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\newlist{tabenum}{enumerate}{1}

\setlist[tabenum,1]{label*=[\arabic*],
                    leftmargin=*,
                    nosep,
                    leftmargin=*,
                    before=\begin{minipage}{\hsize},
                    after=\end{minipage}}


%%% hyperref should be last package in preamble, 
%%% to solve lonely \item error see also:
%%% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/65401/134144
\usepackage{bibentry}
\makeatletter\let\saved@bibitem\@bibitem\makeatother
\usepackage{hyperref}
\makeatletter\let\@bibitem\saved@bibitem\makeatother


%Changes the page numbers - {arabic}=arabic numerals, {gobble}=no page numbers, {roman}=Roman numerals
\pagenumbering{gobble}




\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{key,
  author = {Author, A.},
  year = {2001},
  title = {Title},
  publisher = {Publisher},
}
@article{key2,
  author = {Author, A. and Author B. and Author C.},
  year = {2001},
  title = {a very long article title a very long article title},
  journal = {Journal Name},
}
\end{filecontents}

\bibliographystyle{plain}


\begin{document}


\nobibliography{\jobname}

\noindent \begin{xltabular}{\textwidth}{@{} l X l}

\noindent  \LARGE{\textbf{John A. Doe}} \\
\vspace{-2ex}
\\\toprule
\normalsize \\

\Large{Contact} & \textbf{Full name} \  John Albert Doe \\
\Large{Information} & \textbf{Email} email1@email.com \\
                    & \indent  \quad  \  email2@email.com \\
                    & \textbf{Mobile} 123456789 \\
                    & \textbf{Address} Home address \\

\\
     
\Large{Research} & \textbf{LaTeX} \\
\Large{Interests} & \indent Stuff. \\
     
\\
     
\Large{Projects} & \\

\Large{Publications}    & \textbf{International} \\
                        & \begin{tabenum}
                            \item \bibentry{key} 
                            \item \bibentry{key2}
                          \end{tabenum}\\
\\

\end{xltabular}



\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Would there be any way to add the publications as lists? So that they're nice and numbered.

Comment: @Seankala: I've edited my answer in order to add a second example in which the entries are numbered.