# bibentry, natbib, and hyper ref conflict when bib entry used for heading

Tags: hyperref, natbib, section-titles, bibentry

I've tried solutions posted in [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/65348/clash-between-bibentry-and-hyperref-with-bibstyle-elsart-harv), [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/81937/hyperref-bibentry-natbib-conflict-incorrect-hyperlink), and other relevant posts to no avail. I'm trying to use `hyperref` in document that uses `natbib` and `bibentry`, but it gives me tons of errors. The major difference between my issue and others posts is that I'm using `bibentry` in a section heading, in which I had to use `\protect` to make it work.

Please see my code below:

```
\begin{filecontents}{test.bib}
    @article{mccarty2018theory,
        author = {McCarty, Nolan and Schickler, Eric},
        date-added = {2021-05-16 19:43:59 -0400},
        date-modified = {2021-05-16 19:43:59 -0400},
        journal = {Annual Review of Political Science},
        pages = {175--193},
        publisher = {Annual Reviews},
        title = {On the theory of parties},
        volume = {21},
        year = {2018}}
}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{hanging}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{apa}
\usepackage{bibentry}
\makeatletter\let\saved@bibitem\@bibitem\makeatother
\usepackage{hyperref}
\makeatletter\let\@bibitem\saved@bibitem\makeatother

\author{Test}
\title{Test}
\titleformat*{\section}{\normalsize\bfseries}
\titleformat*{\subsection}{\normalsize\bfseries}
\titleformat*{\subsubsection}{\normalsize\bfseries}

\makeatletter 
\renewcommand\BR@b@bibitem[2][]{\BR@bibitem[#1]{#2}\BR@c@bibitem{#2}}           
\makeatother
\nobibliography*

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\tableofcontents
\section{\protect\bibentry{mccarty2018theory}} %THIS LINE CAUSES AN ERROR
\cite{mccarty2018theory} blah blah blah ...
\clearpage

\bibliography{test.bib}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Did you try `\section[Alternative Section Title]{\protect\bibentry{mccarty2018theory}}`? I believe `hyperref` will just get into massive trouble trying to make a bookmark out of this section title.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: @ManuelWeinkauf - Your intuition was correct. However, what needs to be fixed is not the optional argument of `\section` but the material that has to go into the bookmarks column.

Answer (score 1):

The issue you're encountering is caused by the fact that the argument of `\section` far exceeds `hyperref`'s ability to create an associated bookmark. You need to employ the `\texorpdfstring` macro as the argument of `\section` -- and make sure that the second argument of `\texorpdfstring` isn't too complicated. In fact, I would keep that second argument as simple as possible while still being sufficiently informative. E.g., `McCarty and Schickler, 2018, On the theory of parties`.

[image]

```
\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{test.bib}
\@article{mccarty2018theory,
        author        = {McCarty, Nolan and Schickler, Eric},
        date-added    = {2021-05-16 19:43:59 -0400},
        date-modified = {2021-05-16 19:43:59 -0400},
        journal       = {Annual Review of Political Science},
        pages         = {175--193},
        publisher     = {Annual Reviews},
        title         = {On the theory of parties},
        volume        = {21},
        year          = {2018},
}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
%%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % that's the default nowadays
\usepackage{amsmath}
%%\usepackage{amsfonts} % is loaded automatically by 'amssymb'
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat*{\section}{\normalsize\bfseries}
\titleformat*{\subsection}{\normalsize\bfseries}
\titleformat*{\subsubsection}{\normalsize\bfseries}

\usepackage{hanging}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{apa}
\usepackage{bibentry}
\usepackage[colorlinks,allcolors=blue]{hyperref}

\makeatletter
\let\saved@bibitem\@bibitem
%\let\@bibitem\saved@bibitem
\renewcommand\BR@b@bibitem[2][]{\BR@bibitem[#1]{#2}\BR@c@bibitem{#2}}           
\makeatother

\nobibliography*

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\bigskip\hrule\bigskip

\section{\texorpdfstring{%
   \protect\bibentry{mccarty2018theory}}{%
   McCarty and Schickler, 2018, On the theory of parties}} 

\cite{mccarty2018theory} \dots

\bigskip\hrule\bigskip

\bibliography{test}

\end{document}
```